# Get GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to work in Digital Ocean

Tags: digital-ocean

Good morning,

I'm trying to properly setup GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) in my droplet. I've currently added the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable. Its value is the content of the json key file (containing credentials to verify usage of a Google Service), which is required to start the application.

On startup this environment variable is recognized, but Google needs the value to be an actual json file instead. A simple solution would be to add the key file to my repo and link the environment variable to that file. This is however unsafe.

Is there a way to generate a json file on startup, which contains the value I put in the environment variable? This is a solution which appears to work in Heroku (https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack/issues/2#issuecomment-580212700), but I haven't found something similar in Digital Ocean.

Of course any solution is welcome, as long as I don't have to commit my json file to a repo.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever come right with this? I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: @Phobos, unfortunately not. I ended up committing the json file to my repo (it was a poc anyway), still annoyed I couldn't get it to work though...

Comment: @Airrudi cool, thanks anyway. I'm gonna have a crack at this and will let you know if I come up with a solution - unfortunately I need to use it for a production application so I've got not choice but to figure it out :D

Comment: Ok so the solution we ended up opting for was setting separate environment variables for the client_email, private_key and project_id fields and initialising the app (in our case firebase admin) with those instead. Not as nice as using the .json file but hey, it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Phobos!